# How to add footer template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, footer

How to add footer template only for product view page in Magento 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create catalog_product_view.xml at `app/design/fronten/{ThemevendorName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Catalog/layout`

and add below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="{BlockName}" name="my.block" template="{TemplateFileCloation}"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Still its not working. It's throwing invalid template file